# Can I increase the maximum number of scans in iwlist?

Tags: kernel, wifi

There are very many APs.
In my opinion, there are at least 200 APs in this field.

Scanning with `iwlist` will only scan up to `128` scans.
The debug information of `wpa_supplicant` is limited to a maximum of `128` scans.
I think the kernel limits the number of scans to `128`.

Is there a way to increase this list being scanned?
I would like to see all of the APs in the field without limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using wifi as a `realtek` chip.
The maximum number of ssids at scan time is affected by [`MAX_BSS_CNT`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6f0d349d922ba44e4348a17a78ea51b7135965b1/drivers/staging/rtl8723bs/include/rtw_mlme.h#L11).

The `bss_max_count` option of wpa_supplicant is only a memory option for wpa_supplicant.

In my realtek kernel device driver, `MAX_BSS_CNT` was set to `128`.
I set `MAX_BSS_CNT` to 4 and confirmed that only up to 4 scans can be done.

Answer (score 1):

```
Maximum number of BSS entries to keep in memory
Default: 200
This can be used to limit memory use on the BSS entries (cached scan
results). A larger value may be needed in environments that have huge number
of APs when using ap_scan=1 mode.
bss_max_count=200
```

source: [Example wpa_supplicant configuration file](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf)

---

Also, check section ap_scan=`n` in `wpa_supplicant.conf`

`ap_scan=0` - driver scans the access point.

`ap_scan=1` - wpa_supplicant scans the access point, used by default.

`ap_scan=2` - like 0, but also takes into account sec. policies and SSID, works with [NDISwrapper](http://ndiswrapper.sourceforge.net/).

---

**tl;dr**

ap_scan — AP scanning/selection

By default, wpa_supplicant requests driver to perform AP scanning and then uses the scan results to select a suitable AP. Another alternative is to allow the driver to take care of AP scanning and selection and use wpa_supplicant just to process EAPOL frames based on IEEE 802.11 association information from the driver.

1: wpa_supplicant initiates scanning and AP selection (default).
0: Driver takes care of scanning, AP selection, and IEEE 802.11 association parameters (e.g., WPA IE generation); this mode can also be used with non-WPA drivers when using IEEE 802.1X mode;
do not try to associate with APs (i.e., external program needs to control association). This mode must also be used when using wired Ethernet drivers.

2: like 0, but associate with APs using security policy and SSID (but not BSSID); this can be used, e.g., with ndiswrapper and NDIS drivers to enable operation with hidden SSIDs and optimized roaming;
in this mode, the network blocks in the configuration are tried one by one until the driver reports successful association; each network block should have explicit security policy (i.e., only one
option in the lists) for key_mgmt, pairwise, group, proto variables.

Note: ap_scan=2 should not be used with the nl80211 driver interface (the current Linux interface). ap_scan=1 is optimized work working with nl80211. For finding networks using hidden SSID, scan_ssid=1 in the network block can be used with nl80211.

Comment: also can change DEFAULT_BSS_MAX_COUNT.